# Is learning to do a task automatically an example of intuition?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, terminology, intuition, automaticity, procedural-memory

I'm looking for some examples to understand what people call their intuition at work when making their decisions.

For example:

- We learn to type and then after some time we begin to type
  by automatically knowing position of alphabet on the
  keyboard.
- We learn to ride a vehicle and then after some time we ride it without
  having to think.

Are these the examples of what we call our **intuition**? If not, how do they happen?

Answer (score 9):

No, these are not examples of [intuition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuition_%28psychology%29%20), but examples of [procedural memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_memory) (or [automaticity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automaticity)). Procedural memory is the ability to perform certain tasks without conscious awareness.

Comment: Does procedural memory also work at unconscious level of mind same as intuition? or could it be stored in sub-conscious mind?

Comment: I do not understand the difference between "work at unconscious level of mind" and "stored in sub-conscious mind". Furthermore, please note that "sub-conscious" is not a construct you would use in cognitive psychology.

Comment: Can also be described in terms of automaticity : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automaticity