# Can thought be shifted between subconscious and conscious awareness?

Tags: perception, consciousness

While awake, can thought activity be transferred between the subconscious and conscious awareness, by will?

Comment: You should read [this question & answer](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/992/29) to learn the proper terminology and with it find the answer to your own question.

Comment: @ArtemKaznatcheev: I have seen that one, doesn't help...

Comment: if you have seen it, then why are you using the unscientific term 'subconscious'? If you simply used the scientific terms, you would answer your own question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the scientific literature would necessarily describe the process as "shifting thought between subconscious and conscious awareness" but putting exact definitions aside, obviously this does occur.

When I recall information, in some sense information is being moved from the unconscious to the conscious part of my mind. By focusing on a different task I am able to switch my attention to something else. Thus, what was previously the focus of my consciousness no longer is.

You could think about top-down versus bottom up processes of allocating attention, where top-down refers to where attention is driven more by the individual and bottom-up refers to when attention is driven more by environmental cues.

There are also many other psychological constructs that are concerned with self-regulation of conscious experience. See for example [thought suppression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thought_suppression) and [avoidance coping strategies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coping_%28psychology%29#Types_of_coping_strategies).